# Force update file timestamp in VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, copy, timestamp

I am using the following code to copy a file:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(strOldFile, strNewFile)
```

But the trouble is that the newly-created file inherits the old file's timestamp. Is there a way to force the timestamp to update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit the CreationTime using the [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) class.

```
Dim path = Path.GetTempFileName();
Dim fi As New FileInfo(path)
fi.CreationTime = DateTime.Now;
fi.LastWriteTime = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: That's great. I've converted it to VB.net, and added lastWriteTime, as well as creationtime. Hope that's ok.

Comment: Yep, that will work fine. Sorry - didn't spot you were on VB or I'd have written it in that language! I've changed your code very slightly to use `DateTime.Now` as I think it's a bit easier to read :-)

Comment: Even better. Question nailed! High-5!